# Can I get visual feedback from copying wth Ctrl+C?

Tags: unity, notification, clipboard, clipboard-manager

Lots of times I need to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>) multiple times to copy something. I would appreciate visual feedback that says "a new thing has been copied" or something like that. Is there someway to add this to Ubuntu?

Comment: You could maybe set up a keybinding which doesn't capture the key combo, just sends a notification using `notify-send` (from `libnotify-bin`).

Comment: @marko I'm not sure why you deleted your answer. I flagged it for moderator attention requesting that it be undeleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I adapted my script to react on clipboard changes from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/942280/367990) so that it shows a native notification bubble whenever you copy something:

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Configuration:
APPNAME = "Clipboard Notifier"  # an arbitrary application name
TITLE = "Clipboard modified"    # the bold headline of each notification
ICON = "edit-paste"             # name of the icon to show
MAXLENGTH = 100                 # maximum message length

# Imports:
import gi
import signal
import notify2
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

# Set up signal handler for killing the script with Ctrl+C from terminal:
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

# Initialize the notifications library:
notify2.init(APPNAME)

# Callback function to handle clipboard modification events:
def callback(*args):
    # Get new clipboard content:
    text = clip.wait_for_text()
    # Truncate long content to avoid huge notification bubbles:
    body = text if len(text) < MAXLENGTH else text[:MAXLENGTH] + "..."
    # Create and show notification bubble:
    notify2.Notification(TITLE, body, ICON).show()

# Set up clipboard and register callback for change events
clip = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
clip.connect("owner-change", callback)

# Start Gtk main loop and wait for events:
Gtk.main()
```

Save that somewhere (e.g. as `/usr/local/bin/clipboard-notifier` - you need `sudo` to be allowed to write in that location though, alternatively put it in `~/bin`) and make it executable using the command `chmod +x FILENAME`.

My script uses the Python 3 package `notify2` to display the native notification bubbles. This package is normally not installed by default, you have to add it first with the command below:

```
sudo apt install python3-notify2
```

If you want, you can modify the values of the capitalized variables near the beginning of the script to your needs, especially `TITLE` and `MAXLENGTH` might be useful to change.

Then simply [add it to your startup applications](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/367990) and it will launch automatically when you log in the next time. You can also launch the script manually from e.g. the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> HUD in Unity.

Comment: I appear to be missing a requirement. ImportError: No module named 'notify2'

Comment: @ElderGeek Yes, I just noticed I forgot writing that you have to `sudo apt install python3-notify2` first. Added that now, thanks for paying attention.

Comment: That did the trick. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I've created a more standard solution using bash scripting only without extra libraries:

Here is how I did it:

Create a file called: `clp-notify` and make it executable.

Save the file to: `/home/$USER/add-ons/scripts/clp-notify`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Script $0 started..."
notify-send -u normal -t 3000 -i info 'Script Started!' $0

clip_command="xclip -selection clipboard -o"
current_value=`$clip_command`

while true
do
   new_value=`$clip_command`

   if [[ ! ("$current_value" == "$new_value") ]];
   then      
      echo 'Clipboard Modified...'
      notify-send -u normal -t 3000 -i info 'Clipboard Modified!' 'Your clipboard has been modified.'

      current_value=$new_value
   else
      echo "Polliing..."
   fi

   sleep 1.5
done
```

Next, I created a second file called `start-clipboard-polling` that invokes the above script and it is this second file that gets added to start-up:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

script_path=/home/$USER/add-ons/scripts/clp-notify

function IsClipboardPollingRunning
{
   if (ps -A | grep -q "clp-notify")
   then
      return 1;
   else
      return 0;        
   fi
}

if (IsClipboardPollingRunning == 0)
then
   echo "Starting $script_path"   
   nohup $script_path &
else
   echo "$script_path is already running"
   notify-send -u normal -t 3000 -i info 'Clipboard Notify' "$script_path is already running."
fi
```

The purpose of this second file is to prevent the original `clp-notify` from starting multiple times because the `clp-notify` script will continue to run even if you log out and in or restart the X server.

Then you need to add this `start-clipboard-polling` to your start-up applications.

There is only one problem with this. Although, the second script takes care of preventing `clp-notify` from starting multiple times when you log out and in (because the original instance would be still running from the previous session), the second time you log in, for some reason, the following condition fails:

```bsh
if [[ ! ("$current_value" == "$new_value") ]];
```

and that means notifications will not work. The work around for this is to end the original instance from within `start-clipboard-polling` and restart `clp-notify` as a fresh instance and that's it and then you can delete the section that checks whether `clp-notify` is running but I don't want to use the work around, I am more interested of why it fails.

Otherwise it will continue to work just fine until you log out.

BTW, you need to:

```bsh
sudo apt install xclip
```

Comment: As implemented, `IsClipboardPollingRunning` should be called `IsClipboardPollingNotRunning`, because in shell scripts (unlike most programming) 1 means false and 0 means true. Code like `if (IsClipboardPollingRunning == 0)` in bash is a bug--it does *not* compare anything to 0--and in this case that bug happens to undo the bug in `IsClipboardPollingRunning`. What `if (IsClipboardPollingRunning == 0)` does is to use a subshell (`(` `)`) to call `IsClipboardPollingRunning` and pass two arguments, `==` and `0`, which are ignored. In this script, `if IsClipboardPollingRunning` has the same effect.

Comment: I tried your original script at it existed Sep 30 21:27.  and dropped it in my ~/bin directory, made executable. and tested. Granted it's an infinite loop, but it worked for me. I made no attempt to log out and in as it wasn't something I personally wanted to automate.  It notified as expected on clipboard modification.  I didn't test your second script. You might find this Q&A on bash boolean variables interesting.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953646/how-to-declare-and-use-boolean-variables-in-shell-script

Comment: Thanks, like I said, you can always end-all clp-notify processes from the second script (which would be starting on start-up) and just re-invoke the first script and that would solve the issue (tested it already). I have left the old version of the script here just for other people to see how I had it originally.